# Unable to use gopacket to snoop on connected socket

Tags: go, gopacket

I'm trying to use gopacket to snoop on a socket and print tcp packet payloads. If I start the snooper app first and then connect a tcp socket, things work correctly. If the socket is already connected when the snooper app starts, nothing is printed.

If I pass this option -assembly_debug_log, I get this output:

```
2022/04/22 11:36:10 assembly.go:582: [127.0.0.1->127.0.0.1 43584->80] waiting for start, storing into connection
2022/04/22 11:36:10 assembly.go:582: [127.0.0.1->127.0.0.1 80->43584] waiting for start, storing into connection
2022/04/22 11:36:10 assembly.go:537: ignoring useless packet
2022/04/22 11:36:12 assembly.go:582: [127.0.0.1->127.0.0.1 43584->80] waiting for start, storing into connection
2022/04/22 11:36:12 assembly.go:582: [127.0.0.1->127.0.0.1 80->43584] waiting for start, storing into connection
2022/04/22 11:36:12 assembly.go:537: ignoring useless packet
```

That debug message is under this 'if' in assembly.go:

```
if conn.nextSeq == invalidSequence
```

I don't see any way to set the value of conn.nextSeq.

So it appears that this assembler will squirrel away packets until a SYN packet is received, which it won't since the connection is already established.

Is there a way to print tcp packets from a socket connection that has already been established?

Here is the code:

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "log"

    "github.com/google/gopacket"
    "github.com/google/gopacket/examples/util"
    "github.com/google/gopacket/layers"
    "github.com/google/gopacket/pcap"
    "github.com/google/gopacket/tcpassembly"
    "github.com/google/gopacket/tcpassembly/tcpreader"
)

type myStream struct {
    r tcpreader.ReaderStream
}

func (ms *myStream) run() {
    buf := make([]byte, 4096)
    for {
        n, err := ms.r.Read(buf)
        if err == io.EOF {
            return
        } else if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        log.Println(string(buf[:n]))
    }
}

type myStreamFactory struct{}

func (msf *myStreamFactory) New(_, _ gopacket.Flow) tcpassembly.Stream {
    stream := &myStream{tcpreader.NewReaderStream()}
    go stream.run()
    return &stream.r
}

func main() {
    defer util.Run()()

    flags := log.Flags()
    log.SetFlags(flags | log.Lshortfile)

    handle, err := pcap.OpenLive("lo", 262144, true, pcap.BlockForever)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if err = handle.SetBPFFilter("tcp and port 80"); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    streamFactory := &myStreamFactory{}
    streamPool := tcpassembly.NewStreamPool(streamFactory)
    assembler := tcpassembly.NewAssembler(streamPool)

    packetSource := gopacket.NewPacketSource(handle, handle.LinkType())
    for packet := range packetSource.Packets() {
        if packet.NetworkLayer() == nil || packet.TransportLayer() == nil || packet.TransportLayer().LayerType() != layers.LayerTypeTCP {
            log.Println("Unusable packet")
            continue
        }
        tcp := packet.TransportLayer().(*layers.TCP)
        assembler.AssembleWithTimestamp(packet.NetworkLayer().NetworkFlow(), tcp, packet.Metadata().Timestamp)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a call to `assembler.FlushWithOptions` after creating a new stream, and it seems to be working correctly now.

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "log"
    "time"

    "github.com/google/gopacket"
    "github.com/google/gopacket/examples/util"
    "github.com/google/gopacket/layers"
    "github.com/google/gopacket/pcap"
    "github.com/google/gopacket/tcpassembly"
    "github.com/google/gopacket/tcpassembly/tcpreader"
)

type myStream struct {
    r tcpreader.ReaderStream
}

func (ms *myStream) run() {
    buf := make([]byte, 4096)
    for {
        n, err := ms.r.Read(buf)
        if err == io.EOF {
            return
        } else if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        log.Println(string(buf[:n]))
    }
}

type myStreamFactory struct {
    iWantFlush bool
}

func (msf *myStreamFactory) New(_, _ gopacket.Flow) tcpassembly.Stream {
    stream := &myStream{tcpreader.NewReaderStream()}
    go stream.run()
    msf.iWantFlush = true
    return &stream.r
}

func main() {
    defer util.Run()()

    flags := log.Flags()
    log.SetFlags(flags | log.Lshortfile)

    handle, err := pcap.OpenLive("lo", 262144, true, pcap.BlockForever)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if err = handle.SetBPFFilter("tcp and port 80"); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    streamFactory := &myStreamFactory{}
    streamPool := tcpassembly.NewStreamPool(streamFactory)
    assembler := tcpassembly.NewAssembler(streamPool)

    packetSource := gopacket.NewPacketSource(handle, handle.LinkType())
    for packet := range packetSource.Packets() {
        if packet.NetworkLayer() == nil || packet.TransportLayer() == nil || packet.TransportLayer().LayerType() != layers.LayerTypeTCP {
            log.Println("Unusable packet")
            continue
        }
        tcp := packet.TransportLayer().(*layers.TCP)
        assembler.AssembleWithTimestamp(packet.NetworkLayer().NetworkFlow(), tcp, packet.Metadata().Timestamp)
        if streamFactory.iWantFlush {
            assembler.FlushWithOptions(tcpassembly.FlushOptions{time.Now(), false})
            streamFactory.iWantFlush = false
        }
    }
}
```